# Error al cargar imagenes en browser

Tags: asp.net

Que tal, me encuentro con un problemita al visualizar la imagen en mi navegador al compilar el proyecto, me aparecen como cortadas., ya visualice la ruta, el iis con conteido estatico, apesar de que no lo e subido al servidor y corre en uno virtual
aqui esta el ejemplo:

```
<%@  Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="app_MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>titulo</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body style="height: 79px">
    <div id="cabecera">
        <!-- si funciona-->
        <asp:Image ImageUrl="img/caballo.png" runat="server" ID="logocaballo" />
        <!-- no funciona-->
        <img src="img/caballo.png" />
    </div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                <!-- bloque default -->
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div id="footer">
        <p></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <img src="img/caballo.jpg" />

Comment: podrias poner una imagen del corte de la imagen cuando lo visualizas en el sitio? no intentaste usar el developer tools del browser, al cual accedes con F12, para inspeccionar el html y ver que podrias cortar la imagen

Comment: ya realize la inspeccion, me aparece como error 404 not found 
ahora despues de tanto buscar pude caragarla pero no de esta manera:
         <img src="img/caballo.jpg" />
si no mas bien de esta:
        <asp:Image ImageUrl="img/caballo.png" runat="server" id="logocaballo"/>

Comment: Aun no estoy muy seguro como funcionan los controles de asp
tienes idea de por que funciona de esta ultima forma?

Comment: wink y donde está el código de la imagen?

Comment: una duda la imagen esta dentro del la estructura del sitio web ? porque sino lo esta el ~/ no funciona. La imagen deberia estar en la carpeta donde esta el resto de las paginas. Alli debes ubicar esa carpeta img

Comment: si usas materpage recuerda que es la pagina aspx quien define la ruta real a la imagen por eso debes usar el ~/ con <asp:Image> como te menciona @CarlosMuñoz en su respuesta

Comment: @wink actualizé mi respuesta, espero que con eso te quede claro porque no funciona de la segunda manera

Answer (score 1):

Apuesto a que sí funciona en el home page pero no en las demás páginas

El problema es que ese tag `<img>` lo estás incluyendo en el MasterPage en el archivo MasterPage.cs

Al momento de construirse las páginas html ese master page no se convierte en una página sino que se incluye como plantilla dentro de otra.

En este caso estoy seguro que tus páginas no están a la misma altura que el masterpage y por lo tanto la url es incorrecta ya que es realtiva a pàgina y no al masterpage.

En cambio cuando usas el control de web forms, asp.net sabe como resolver correctamente la url, algo que no es posible en html puro ya que éste no entiende de masterpages.

La forma que te recomiendo en todo caso es usar siempre las rutas relativas  a la raiz de la aplicación en una de las dos maneras siguientes

#### Versión asp.net

```
 <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/img/caballo.png" runat="server" id="logocaballo"/>
```

La ruta `"~/img/caballo.png"` es convertida a una ruta relativa a la raíz de tu aplicación, donde el símbolo `~` representa a la raíz no importando donde haya sido desplegado dentro del IIS

#### Versión html

Si no quieres utilizar un control lado servidor de asp.net puedes utilizar directamente el img de esta forma:

```
<img src="<%: ResolveUrl("~/img/caballo.jpg") %>" />
```

De esta manera siempre garantizas que estás apuntando a la dirección correcta.

Comment: lo he probado pero esta manera sigue sin funcionar
        "~/img/caballo.png"
de lo contrario esta otra funciona a la perfeccion
        <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/img/caballo.png" runat="server" id="logocaballo"/>

pero no entiendo cual es la diferencia de ambas.

Comment: Por favor incluye el código completo en tu pregunta, no como comentario, sino edita tu pregunta. Así podremos ver exactamente cual es el error

Answer (score 0):

Si estas definiendo imágenes con path relativo como en este caso:

```
   <img src="img/imagen.jpg" />
```

Significa que dentro de la raíz de tu proyecto debes tener un folder `/img` y dentro una imagen `imagen.jpg`.

Puedes buscar si realmente existe el folder y la imagen, que debe estar al mismo nivel que default.aspx

Comment: si, el nivel de los ficheros esta en su orden respectivo.
el detalle esta en que solo me respeta esta manera
        <asp:Image ImageUrl="img/caballo.png" runat="server" id="logocaballo"/>

No de la manera estandart que has mencionado ya.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me pasaba algo similar solo que no carga ninguna img o archivo .js 
en un proyecto de asp en c# cuando cambiaba el puerto de la aplicación
demore un día en encontrar el error
lo pille en web.config comente el codigo y se arreglo

```
<!--
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
-->
```